# Navigator causes Invariant Violation

Tags: react-native

I tried to create a new React-Native project and include a Navigator.
But this causes an error.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar, Navigator, TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';


const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{title: 'Awesome Scene', index: 0}}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) => <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text>}
        style={{padding: 100}}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This happens both on Android and iOS.

-react-native: "0.61.2",

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

You can't declare a const like that using `:`

change it to `=`
this will solve your problem

```
const App = () => React$Node = () => {
```

Comment: This came actually from the react-native init boilerplate. When I remove the navigator and leave the standard code it works fine.